# AWS EC2 Security Group Web access from a single country?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to setup an AWS EC2 security group to allow web traffic from only one country? If so, how?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) if you haven't already.

Comment: @kce - how is this against the FAQ?

Comment: @EEAA Well, posting exact duplicates of your own question is, for one.

Comment: @EEAA - In my opinion it's not (although the question is missing a lot of detail). His other question was closed (erroneously in my opinion) and this one already has another vote against it. I was just suggesting it seeing as he's a new user.

Comment: Ahh, dupe. Good catch.

Comment: So this question (obviously a question) is a dup of the one that was closed as being NOT a question? Also, there is NO answer to the question there, instead I get "Why would you want to do that" and an answer that circumvents AWS. There IS an answer to the question here, however, which I will now try to mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know all of that country's netblocks?

If so, then yes, it's possible, though it may take multiple groups, as there's a 100-rule limit per SG for classic EC2 and a 50-rule limit for VPC SGs.

Whether or not this is a good thing to do, though, is another question altogether.